# How can I use kbgetc in xv6

Tags: xv6

I want use kbdgetc() in user mode.
I need to use it to program a vim-like software in xv6.
I try to use kernel mode, but I totally don't know how to do it.

Comment: Why do you need to call an interrupt handler from user space? `kbdgetc()` is called when it's needed (when an interrupt is generated by the keyboard (`IRQ_KBD`). If you need to read for the console, you can use `read(0,...)`

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you want some non-buffering reading on `fd` 0?

To achieve this behavior, you can modify `consoleintr` function that is responsible of it.

First add some variable internal to the kernel to disable or not buffering.

Lets call it `non_buffering` and set its default values to `0`.

Then add a system call to change this value (or modify an existing, as you want)

Change `consoleintr` this way (modification is line 221):

```
191 void
192 consoleintr(int (*getc)(void))
193 {
194   int c, doprocdump = 0;
195
196   acquire(&cons.lock);
197   while((c = getc()) >= 0){
198     switch(c){
   ....
216     default:
217       if(c != 0 && input.e-input.r < INPUT_BUF){
218         c = (c == '\r') ? '\n' : c;
219         input.buf[input.e++ % INPUT_BUF] = c;
220         consputc(c);

       /* NON_BUFFERING added here */
221         if(non_buffering || c == '\n' || c == C('D') || input.e == input.r+INPUT_BUF){
222           input.w = input.e;
223           wakeup(&input.r);
224         }
225       }
226       break;
227     }
228   }
229   release(&cons.lock);
230   if(doprocdump) {
231     procdump();  // now call procdump() wo. cons.lock held
232   }
233 }
```